# Cookies in Google Chrome not created from time to time

Tags: php, google-chrome, codeigniter, cookies

Since few days I observed strange behaviour in Google Chrome connected with Cookies.

I have three environments:

- HTTPS://somedomain.com (release env)
- HTTP://dev.somedomain.com (development env)
- HTTP://demo.somedomain.com (development env for demo)

Example:
A. for development env. (HTTP://dev.somedomain.com and HTTP://demo.somedomain.com)

- On Monday everything works fine
- On Thursday Google Chrome removes session cookie "ci_session" (cookie disapeared) and webapp cannot regenerate it again anymore
- When I clear Google Chrome browsing data everything back to normal but the situation repeats in couple days

B. for release env. (HTTPS://somedomain.com)

- problem not exists
- even If I manualy remove session cookie "ci_session" webapp regenerate it without problems

C. for local env (HTTP://localhost)

- problem not exists
- even If I manualy remove session cookie "ci_session" webapp regenerate it without problems

My comments:

It seems that the problem exists:

- only in Google Chrome (not in Safari, Opera, Edge, Firefox)
- only for HTTP and not for HTTPS protocol
- OR/AND only for subdomain (but I am not sure if it is true)
- exits for webapp installed on the internet (hosted server)
- not exists when I run webapp localy installed on my PC development env.
- problem occured on 2 different PCs with Win10 & Chrome

Please help:

- Any ideas how to handle this issue?
- Where to search the reason?
- What I can check?
- Any suggestion can be helpful

My configuration:

- Windows 10
- newest Google Chrome
- Web app on hosting server (not local)
- PHP 7.4
- CogeIgniter 3.1.11
- config.php:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 86400; //=24h (1h=3600)
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['cookie_prefix'] = '';
$config['cookie_domain'] = '';
$config['cookie_path'] = '/';
$config['cookie_secure'] = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly'] = FALSE;
```